# Drag and Drop in Android Studio layout editor

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio

I have a problem with adding images to my app's layout. I've searched for an answer for a while, but even when doing exactly what friendly people of the internet told me, there is still no success.

- images are in PNG format in res/drawable folder.
- im trying to drag'n'drop them into the content_*.xml preview.
- i can add elements from the palette.
- i am using RelativeLayout.

Any idea what may be the cause of this problem?

View of my android studio screen:

[image: one]

Comment: You need to place imageview and set src or background..
you can't  directly drag and drop images ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You must store your images on `Drawables` folders not in `drawable`
    -drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi.....
2. You should drag an `ImageView`, then add the image with the `src param`. You can't directly drag and drop images
3. You can't add elements in "Palette".
4. `RelativeLayout`... Okay, whatever layout it's good

**UPDATE1**

1. To see the drawable folders you must clic on arrow (see image1) and put on "Project" (image2)

[image: one]

[image: two]

2. ----------> see point 1.
3. Yes you can drag&drop that elemenst, `TextViews, ImageViews, Edittext....`

Comment: 1. Drawables, in which directory? If i create 'Drawables' folder in place of 'drawable', Android Studio doesn't see it.
2. This works, but i can't access my images.
3. I meant drag'n'dropping elements (for example ImageView) from the palette to the design view.

Thank you for your very fast answer.

Comment: @MichałRomasiuk Check my **UPDATE1**

Comment: ok, took me some time, but i got it. big thanks for your time. :)

Comment: @MichałRomasiuk I'm glad to listen that. =)

Comment: @MichałRomasiuk Gradle will organize your drawables so that if one drawable has multiple instances for different DPIs, it will organize them (interface only) into a single folder.

Answer (score 0):

you should drag an ImageView, then add the image with the src param (you can do this in the right menu or with xml)